# Do Total Market funds include all market capitalizations?

Tags: investing, index-fund

Building up my IRA and one of the funds I want to use is FSKAX. When I was looking at its [composition](https://fundresearch.fidelity.com/mutual-funds/composition/315911693), it says its a "Large Blend" and that 99.11% of its portfolio invest in companies with a value greater than $10bn, which I believe means Large Cap. The index it seeks to match is the [DWCF](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/d/dow-jones-total-market-index.asp), but I've read that it includes stocks from all market capitalizations.

Does a Total Market fund actually cover more than just large cap? Or does it mean "total market" by including all sectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a total market fund should include small-, mid-, and large-cap equities. In the case of FSKAX, it follows the Dow Jones US Total Market Index, which from your link:

> The Dow Jones U.S. Market Index (DWCF) is a total market index that represents the top 95% of the U.S. stock market based on market capitalization.

So by definition the smallest 5% are excluded.

Additionally, it is [capitalization-weigthed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capitalization-weighted_index), meaning it holds more of the larger equities and less of the smaller.

These factors may make FSKAX, in particular, look more like large-cap fund than a total-market fund.

---

If you read the **Objective** section of [Fidelity's page on FSKAX](https://fundresearch.fidelity.com/mutual-funds/summary/315911693), you'll see (emphasis mine):

> Seeks to provide investment results that correspond to the total return of **a broad range of United States stocks**.

Compare this to the objective listed for [VTSAX](https://fundresearch.fidelity.com/mutual-funds/summary/922908728):

> The investment seeks to track the performance of a benchmark index that measures the investment return of the overall stock market.

---

So yes, a total-market index fund *should* include all capitalizations, but whether a particular fund does, or to what extent, will vary between individual funds. If you aren't happy with a particular fund's coverage of the market, either invest in a different fund instead, or in an additional fund to supplement what is missing.

Comment: Regardless of how they're described, the portfolios of FSKAX and VTSAX are virtually identical: 3532 holdings versus 3669, and I'm sure nearly all the differences are at the low end of market capitalization.

Comment: Those numbers look a bit closer than the last time I checked (maybe a year ago?). Fidelity also has FZROX, a "total market" index fund with zero expense ratio, but it holds even fewer stocks than FSKAX (I think less than 3k last I checked)

Comment: Yeah I suspect they add holdings as they grow in size, and in terms of assets VTSAX > FSKAX > FZROX.

Comment: FZROX is also really new compared to the other two.